# Create a dynamic column to flag existing data from select query

Tags: sql, select

I have 4 tables named student, address, phone and record, where I can use the first column to join each.

**student**

```
+----+-------------+
| id | studentName |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | Name_1      |
|  2 | Name_2      |
+----+-------------+
```

**address**

```
+----+-------------+
| id | addressName |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | address_1   |
|  1 | address_2   |
|  2 | address_3   |
+----+-------------+
```

**phone**

```
+----+-------------+
| id | phoneNumber |
+----+-------------+
|  1 |      123456 |
|  2 |      987654 |
+----+-------------+
```

**record**

```
+----+-----------+
| id | recNumber |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | REC001    |
|  2 | REC002    |
+----+-----------+
```

---

A select query

```
select s.id,s.studentName,a.addressName,p.phoneNumber,r.recNumber
from student s
 join address a on  s.id=a.id
 join phone p on  s.id=p.id
 join  record r on s.id=r.id
```

on these tables gives me an output

```
+----+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
| id | studentName | addressName | phoneNumber | recNumber |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  1 | Name_1      | address_1   |      123456 | REC001    |
|  1 | Name_1      | address_2   |      123456 | REC001    |
|  2 | Name_2      | address_3   |      987654 | REC002    |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
```

I want to transform it into something like

```
+----+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+-----------+
| id | studentName | addressName | phoneNumber | recNumber | flag      |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+-----------+
|  1 | Name_1      | address_1   | null        | null      | address   |
|  1 | Name_1      | address_2   | null        | null      | address   |
|  2 | Name_2      | address_3   | null        | null      | address   |
|  1 | Name_1      | null        | 123456      | null      | phone     |
|  2 | Name_2      | null        | 987654      | null      | phone     |
|  1 | Name_1      | null        | null        | REC001    | record    |
|  2 | Name_2      | null        | null        | REC002    | record    |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+-----------+
```

the value in `flag` column need not be the table name, any constant is fine.

I have done it using temptable (By adding entire details into one temp table and by re-inserting data with flag). 
Is there any option to get it directly?

[rextester](http://rextester.com/WMRN25337) with the above data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with `UNION`:

```
SELECT id, studentName, addressName, 
       NULL AS phoneNumber, NULL as recNumber, 'address' as flag
FROM student s
JOIN address a ON s.id = a.id

UNION

SELECT id, studentName, NULL, 
       phoneNumber, NULL, 'phone' as flag
FROM student s
JOIN phone p ON s.id = p.id

UNION

SELECT id, studentName, NULL, 
       NULL, recNumber, 'record' as flag
FROM student s
JOIN record r ON s.id = r.id
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It really never occur to me to use union as my actual data and tables are really big.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the extra column using CASE WHEN with LEFT OUTER JOIN in your query

```
select s.id,s.studentName,a.addressName,p.phoneNumber,r.recNumber, 
CASE WHEN a.addressName IS NOT NULL THEN 'address'
WHEN p.phoneNumber IS NOT NULL THEN 'phone'
ELSE 'record' AS flag 
from student s
 LEFT OUTER join address a on  s.id=a.id
 LEFT OUTER join phone p on  s.id=p.id
 LEFT OUTER join  record r on s.id=r.id
```